# How to pass method references with parameters into Arrays.stream?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have a method from an interface that goes through an array of items and buffs and calculates the sum of all of a certain method like so:

```
@Override
public float getDamageReduction(EntityPlayable playable) {
    float bonus = (float) Arrays.stream(items).filter(Objects::nonNull).mapToDouble(Item::getDamageReduction(this)).sum();
    float buffBonus = (float)buffs.stream().mapToDouble(Buff::getDamageReduction(this)).sum();
    return bonus + buffBonus;
}
```

This code doesn't work because you can't `Buff::getDamageReduction(this)` because you're not allowed to use method references with parameters.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a method-reference in this case. You can write a lambda expression instead.

```
float bonus = (float) Arrays.stream(items)
                            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                            .mapToDouble(item -> item.getDamageReduction(this))
                            .sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use function references in this way. You could create `Function` outside your stream this way:

```
Function<Item, Double> func1 = item -> item.getDamageReduction(this);
```

and respectively for the second line

```
Function<Buff, Double> func2 = buff -> buff.getDamageReduction(this);
```

and then use it as follows:

```
float bonus = (float)Arrays.stream(items)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .mapToDouble(func1)
    .sum();
```

But I think that much simpler is just to write:

```
float bonus = (float)Arrays.stream(items)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .mapToDouble(item -> item.getDamageReduction(this))
    .sum();
```